# iOS: AFHTTPSession manager response data

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, afhttprequestoperation, afnetworking-3, afhttpsessionmanager

in my app I'm using the new AFN 3.0 and I have

> AFHTTPSessionManager *manager

instead of

> AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation

my problem is that before I was able to get some data from RequestOperation as:

```
NSURL *url = operation.request.URL;

//or

NSNumber statusCode = operation.response.statusCode;

//or

NSData *responseData = operation.responseData;
```

and how can I get this elements with AFHTTPSessionManager?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in v2 you were getting `AFHTTPRequestOperation` for the request

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

But in the v3 you will get `NSURLSessionTask`

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

So based on that you can get the details the from the `NSURLSessionTask` like the `currentRequest` , `response` etc

For more changes and details, you can refer to the migration guide of AFNetworking 
[AFNetworking Migration Guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide)

For NSURLSessionTask Reference : [NSURLSessionTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTask_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionTask/state)